# android webview progress: any good solution?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to have a busy indicator of some sort when pages are loading. My indicator will be full-screen like a splash screen. This is because the android webview blanks the page to white before it starts loading, unlike a normal browser.

A simple solution might be suggested. for example, set loading true in `onPageStarted()` and set false in `onPageFinished()`.

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              setLoading(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                setLoading(true);
        }
```

the problem with this is that the website i'm loading results in multiple start / finished cycles for a single click. maybe this is redirects, or iframes. i'm not sure ... but the result is that the "busy" indicator flashes on and off disturbingly.

Considering that, another ideas is to keep a count of pages loading- incrementing in `onPageStarted()` and decrementing in `onPageFinished()`. something like this,

```
        private int loadingCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            loadingCount--;
            if (loadingCount == 0) {
              setLoading(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (loadingCount == 0) {
                setLoading(true);
            }
            loadingCount++;
        }
```

I'm running into this problem: page started / page finished are not matched. I'm not sure why exactly, but I think it might have to do w/ redirects.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private boolean loadingFinished = true, redirect = false;

public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
     if (!loadingFinished) {
        redirect = true;
     }
     loadingFinished = false;
     view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
     return true;
      }


      @Override
      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
     setTitle(url);
     loadingFinished = false;
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FacebookWebView.this);
     progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
     progressDialog.setMessage(" Loading...");
     progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
     progressDialog.show();
      }


      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     if (!redirect) {
        loadingFinished = true;
     }
     if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
           progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
            //finish();
     } else {
        redirect = false;
     }
      }
```

I'm not exactly sure, but this should solve your problem with redirects. In the case of several frames on the same page, probably counting in onPageFinished till the number of frames, and then dismiss "busy dialog", should be a solution.

Comment: you set the visibility to `VISIBLE` repeatedly in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` but never set it to anything else. is this correct?